# What am I missing in my custom std::ranges iterator?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'd like to provide a view for a customer data structure, with it's own iterator. I wrote a small program to test it out, shown below. It I uncomment begin(), then it works. But if I use DummyIter, then I get a compile error.

In my full program, I've implemented a full iterator but for simplicity, I narrowed it down to the necessary functions here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct DummyIter
{
  using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
  using value_type = T;
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

  DummyIter() = default;

  auto operator*() const { T t; return t; }

  auto& operator++() { return *this; }

  auto operator++(int val) { DummyIter tmp = *this; ++*this; return tmp; }

  auto operator==(const DummyIter& iter) const { return true; }
};

template<class V>
struct DummyView : std::ranges::view_interface<DummyView<V>>
{
  //auto begin() const { return std::ranges::begin(v); }
  auto begin() const { return DummyIter<int>(); }

  auto end() const { return std::ranges::end(v); }

  V v;
};

int main() {
  auto view = DummyView<std::vector<int>>();
  view | std::views::filter([](auto i) { return i > 0; });
}
```

I'm using GCC 11.1.0. What am I missing in my iterator for it to be ranges compliant?

```
error: no match for 'operator|' (operand types are 'DummyView<std::vector<int> >' and 'std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Filter, main()::<lambda(auto:15)> >')
   37 |   view | std::views::filter([](auto i) { return i > 0; });
      |   ~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |   |                        |
      |   |                        std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Filter, main()::<lambda(auto:15)> >
      |   DummyView<std::vector<int> >
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a [mre] and using features of C++20 that my Visual Studio doesn't even understand.

Comment: You certainly aren't fulfilling all the requirements of `random_access_iterator_tag`

Comment: @Bob__ probably not as it's a dummy implementation

Comment: Compilers support for C++20 is still quite poor, so please specify compiler you are using.

Comment: @Bob__: Probably not, since there's nothing to "add". In fact, @dromodel - why not use `auto operator++(int val) { return *this; }`, like with the other incrementation operator?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The way to check this kind of thing for ranges is:

1. Verify that your iterator is an `input_iterator`.
2. Verify that your sentinel is a `sentinel_for` your iterator.

Those are the checks that will tell you what functionality you're missing.

In this case, that's:

```cpp
using I = DummyIter<int>;
using S = std::vector<int>::const_iterator;

static_assert(std::input_iterator<I>);   // ok
static_assert(std::sentinel_for<S, I>);  // error
```

And the issue there is that `S` isn't a `sentinel_for<I>` because it's not equality comparable. You need to know when the iteration stops, and you don't have that operator - your `DummyIter<T>` is comparable to another `DummyIter<T>`, but not to what you're returning from `end()`.

So you either need to add another `operator==` to `DummyIter<T>`, or have `DummyView<V>::end()` return some kind of `DummySentinel<V>` that is comparable to `DummyIter<T>`. It depends on the real problem which is the better approach, there are examples of both in the standard library.

Answer (score 9):

Because your `DummyView` does not meet the concept of `range`, to be precise, the return type of `view.end()` *cannot* be used as a sentinel for `view.begin()`, because there is no suitable `operator==()` for `DummyIter` to compare with `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`, which means that there is *no way* to know if the iterator has reached the end of the range.

The workaround is just to add `bool operator==(std::vector<int>::const_iterator) const` to your `DummyIter`

```
template<class T>
struct DummyIter {
  // ...
  bool operator==(std::vector<T>::const_iterator) const;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cszd3TeMa)

Answer (score 3):

This can't work since return types of your `begin` and `end` do not match.
So basically those iterators can't be compared to each other.

Prove:

- here is [your code with extra static assert](https://godbolt.org/z/bEW7KTrbf)
- here is [dummy fix](https://godbolt.org/z/Ed5o1ber5) which compiles since now same return type is used for `begin` and `end`

Minimum requirement is that result of `begin()` and `end()` are comparable. Different types for `begin()` and `end()` are useful when size of range is not known. Here is nice [explanation of sentinel](https://www.foonathan.net/2020/03/iterator-sentinel/) (mentioned in comment).

Comment: Doesn't C++20 support ranges having sentinels with types different from the one returned by `begin` (once a proper comparator has been provided)?

Comment: @Bob__ yes, they do, but you do need to provide ability to compare iterator with sentinel, which OP code failed to do.

Comment: @Bob__ actually, it's c++17.

Comment: If he planed to implemented sentinel then he completely lost track how to do it.

Comment: There is no requirement that the return types of `begin` and `end` match.

Comment: bu they have to be comparable (equal or not equal), what did I mentioned in last edit.

Comment: @MarekR The first half of your answer is still wrong.