# Can't pipe user-defined range adaptor with a standard library one

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I was missing `split_when` in my code and, having confirmed it being a [tier 2 addition](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2214r2.html#views), decided to implement it on my own. I am using GCC 13.1.0 and cppreference [claims](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) that it supports *Pipe support for user-defined range adaptors*, with the exception of `std::bind_back()`.

So firstly, I have created my own, slightly worse version of it:

```cpp
namespace detail {
    template <class T, class U>
    struct copy_const
            : std::conditional<std::is_const_v<T>, U const, U> {
    };

    template <class T, class U,
            class X = typename copy_const<std::remove_reference_t<T>, U>::type>
    struct copy_value_category
            : std::conditional<std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T&&>, X&, X&&> {
    };

    template <class T, class U>
    struct type_forward_like
            : copy_value_category<T, std::remove_reference_t<U>> {
    };

    template <class T, class U>
    using type_forward_like_t = typename type_forward_like<T, U>::type;
}

namespace so {
    template <class ConstFn, class... Args>
    constexpr auto bind_back(ConstFn fn, Args&& ... args) {
        using F = ConstFn;

        if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<F> or
                      std::is_member_pointer_v<F>)
            static_assert(fn != nullptr);

        return
        [fn, ... bound_args(
                std::forward<Args>(args))]<class... T>
        (
                T &&... call_args
        )
        {
            return std::invoke(fn, std::forward<T>(call_args)..., bound_args...);
        };
    }
}
```

The inspiration was taken from [cppreference's possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front#Possible_implementation).

Then, having studied [P2387](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2387r3.html), I added the following factory:

```cpp
namespace so {
    namespace views {
        template <typename F>
        class closure : public std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure<closure<F>> {
            F f;
        public:
            constexpr closure(F f) : f(f) { }

            template <std::ranges::viewable_range R>
            requires std::invocable<F const&, R>
            constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(R&& r) const {
                return f(std::forward<R>(r));
            }
        };

        template <typename F>
        class adaptor {
            F f;
        public:
            constexpr adaptor(F f) : f(f) { }

            template <typename... Args>
            constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const {
                if constexpr (std::invocable<F const&, Args...>) {
                    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                } else {
                    return closure(bind_back(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

*Note: the proposal contains typos and was missing `decltype(auto)` from the `constexpr operator()`s.*

Afterwards, I have created my view (and its iterator):

```cpp
namespace so::views {
    template <std::ranges::input_range View, std::predicate<std::ranges::range_value_t<View>> F> requires std::ranges::view<View>
    class SplitWhenView
            : public std::ranges::view_interface<SplitWhenView<View, F>> {
        
        View base_;
        F predicate_;
        
    public:

        SplitWhenView() = default;
        SplitWhenView(View base, F predicate) : base_(std::move(base)), predicate_(std::move(predicate)) {}

        auto base() { return base_; }

        template <std::input_iterator It, std::predicate<std::ranges::range_value_t<View>> Predicate>
        class SplitWhenIterator;

        using iterator = SplitWhenIterator<std::ranges::iterator_t<View>, F>;

        auto begin() { return SplitWhenIterator(std::ranges::begin(base_), std::ranges::end(base_), predicate_); }
        auto end() { return SplitWhenIterator(std::ranges::end(base_), std::ranges::end(base_), predicate_); }
        
    };

    template <std::ranges::input_range View, std::predicate<std::ranges::range_value_t<View>> F> requires
    std::ranges::view<View>
    template <std::input_iterator It, std::predicate<std::ranges::range_value_t<View>> Predicate>
    class SplitWhenView<View, F>::SplitWhenIterator {

        It current_, end_;
        Predicate predicate_;

    public:
        
        using value_type = std::ranges::subrange<It>;

        SplitWhenIterator(It begin, It end, Predicate func)
                : current_{begin}, end_{end}, predicate_{func} {}

        auto operator++() {
            current_ = std::ranges::find_if(current_, end_, predicate_);
            if (current_ != end_)
                ++current_;  // Move past the character we're splitting on
        }

        auto operator*() const -> std::ranges::subrange<It> {
            auto next = std::ranges::find_if(current_, end_, predicate_);
            return {current_, next};
        }

        auto operator<=>(const SplitWhenIterator& rhs) const = default;
    };

    template <std::ranges::range R, std::predicate<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>> F>
    SplitWhenView(R&&, F) -> SplitWhenView<std::views::all_t<R>, F>;
}
```

And, finally, used the pipe factories to create a view:

```cpp
namespace so::views {
    inline constexpr adaptor splitWhen =
            []<std::ranges::viewable_range Range, std::predicate<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>> Predicate>(
                    Range&& range, Predicate&& predicate
            ) {
                return SplitWhenView(std::forward<Range>(range), std::forward<Predicate>(predicate));
            };
}
```

I tried using it like so:

```cpp
auto v = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (auto e : v | so::views::splitWhen([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; })
                | std::views::join ) {
    std::cout << e << ' ';
}
```

which didn't compile[1]. However, if we drop `join` and work on subranges provided by the `splitWhen()`, everything works fine:

```cpp
auto v = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (auto range : v | so::views::splitWhen([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; })) {
    for (auto e : range) std::cout << e << ' ';
}
```

[1]: The compilation error informs us that the compiler rejected the following construct:

```
error: no match for 'operator|' (operand types are 'so::views::SplitWhenView<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int> >, main()::<lambda(int)> >' and 'const std::ranges::views::_Join')
for (auto e : v | so::views::splitWhen([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; })
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                |
                so::views::SplitWhenView<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int> >, main()::<lambda(int)> >
              | std::views::join ) {
              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            |
                            const std::ranges::views::_Join
```

Further down the error rabbit hole, I *think* I found a relevant source of the problem:

```
required for the satisfaction of 'derived_from<_Lhs, std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptorClosure>' [with _Lhs = so::views::SplitWhenView<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, main::._anon_197>]
```

It looks like that in order to pipe through the *standard* views, one needs the user-provided ones to inherit from `std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptorClosure`. Judging from the underscores, this is an internal type to libstdc++, which is unavailable to the end-users.

My guess is that the library implementation does not support the proposal fully (to greater extent than the one which cppreference was talking about (*just* missing `std::bind_back()`). The proposal states that:

> it will be up to the standard library to properly handle them (whether changing those types to inherit from this new thing or having `range_adaptor_closure` additionally recognize the particular implementation’s preexisting range adaptor closure marker instead).

However, I am unsure whether I did everything correctly to make my own view pipeable. Perhaps the problem lies on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `SplitWhenIterator` does not meet the minimum semantic requirements of `std::input_iterator`, so it is not a valid iterator type, which makes `SplitWhenView` not actually a range. In other words, `v | so::views::splitWhen(...)` is *not* a range, so `views::join` cannot be applied.

`std::input_iterator` requires that the iterator type must have a valid `difference_type` member and a pre-increment operator whose return type is a reference to itself. In addition, it needs to have a post-increment operator, which `SplitWhenIterator` lacks.

Also, since `SplitWhenIterator` is not default-constructible, it does not satisfy the semantics of a sentinel, which cannot serve as its own sentinel.

The minimum modification to make `SplitWhenIterator` satisfy `input_iterator` and `sentinel_for` itself would be:

```
template <std::input_iterator It, std::predicate<std::ranges::range_value_t<View>> Predicate>
class SplitWhenView<View, F>::SplitWhenIterator {

    It current_, end_;
    Predicate predicate_;

public:
    
    using value_type = std::ranges::subrange<It>;
    using difference_type = std::ranges::range_difference_t<View>;

    SplitWhenIterator() = default;
    SplitWhenIterator(It begin, It end, Predicate func)
            : current_{begin}, end_{end}, predicate_{func} {}

    auto operator++() -> SplitWhenIterator& {
        current_ = std::ranges::find_if(current_, end_, predicate_);
        if (current_ != end_)
            ++current_;  // Move past the character we're splitting on
        return *this;
    }

    auto operator++(int) {
      if constexpr (std::forward_iterator<It>) {
        auto tmp = *this;
        ++*this;
        return tmp;
      } else
        ++*this;
    }

    auto operator*() const -> std::ranges::subrange<It> {
        auto next = std::ranges::find_if(current_, end_, predicate_);
        return {current_, next};
    }

    auto operator<=>(const SplitWhenIterator& rhs) const = default;
};
```

which will make your first example valid ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z7WhxWqeo)).

There is a good way to verify that a custom iterator type is standard-conforming, see [What am I missing in my custom std::ranges iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71529455/11638718)

Comment: Ahh, satisfying the iterator requirements. I seem to always forget about those. Thank you! Shame that the full error did not mention anything about those constraints being unsatisfied.